# Can I prevent this operation from returning an answer in Scientific Notation?

Tags: php, math

I've got a fairly simple formula, although it involves a large-ish number, which is basically this:

```
$one = 1300391053;   
$two = 0.768;

// $millitime = 1.30039116114E+12    
$millitime = ($one+$two)*1000;
```

I understand this is the technically correct answer but I'm expecting to get `1300391053768`. The goal of this is to get the time in milliseconds. I could combine the two and remove the decimal although that feels a bit odd.

Is there a way to get this to store 'properly' ?

[ as as side note, it seems not all installations handle this the same. My local PHP install (v5.3 on MacOS) returns the sci notation, but I run the identical code writecodeonline.com and get what I'm expecting/wanting. ]

Comment: Czechnology makes a good point - the number is stored as a number (ie, properly), it's just displaying in scientific notation.  Your solution is in the display, not the storage.

Answer (score 3):

try using php's [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

so:

```
$one = 1300391053;   
$two = 0.768;
$millitime = number_format(($one+$two)*1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

What is "storing properly"? <strike>If you use `print_r($millitime);` you'll get `1300391053768`.</strike> The value is stored "properly", the only question is how you want the output formatted. You could use [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) or [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) for it.

```
echo sprintf('%.0f', $millitime) . PHP_EOL; // 1300391053768
echo sprintf('%e',   $millitime) . PHP_EOL; // 1.300391e+12

echo number_format($millitime, 0, '.', '') . PHP_EOL; // 1300391053768
```

Comment: actually if you use print_r($millitime) you get different results on different versions of PHP, which was my point.

Comment: @Will, ok. I posted it before your edit. Anyway, the rest should work.